# Export Spillover_Table to Excel in R

Tags: r, excel, export

another Day, another Question.

Now i need to Export my Spillover_Table,

```
Sigma_DY12_F_all<- spilloverDY12(Sigma_est, n.ahead = 12, no.corr = F)
```

to an Excel-file.
I couldn't figure out how to do this.
So far I have exported the results to a text file and then manually copied them to Excel.

```
cat(capture.output(print(Sigma_DY12_F_all), file = ".../Results/Bank Connectedness_DY12_F_all.txt"))

typeof(Sigma_DY12_F_all)
```

The Type of the Table is a List.

how can I save the results in an Excel-file without copying them manually?

Thanks for helping :)

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to use this package:

```
library(openxlsx)
```

Then,

```
write.xlsx()
```

See help file `?openxlsx::write.xlsx` for argument details.

Comment: This is my code
**write.xlsx(as.data.frame(Sigma_DY12_F_all),file="C:/.../Results/aaaaa.xlsx", asTable = TRUE)**
gives Error
**Error in as.data.frame.default(Sigma_DY12_F_all) : 
  cannot coerce class ‘"spillover_table"’ to a data.frame**